# Calculate duration for date ranges without overlaps

Tags: javascript, duration, date-range

Quite recently I had the problem to compute the total amount of multiple date durations and I did not now how to do it. Lets say you have 5 date ranges and you want to compute the total amount of the duration without adding the overlapping ranges twice or three times... . How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a lot about it I came up with an easy solution: You add all the start and end dates to a list and sort the dates in the list. Then you go from the left through the right and add all sub ranges between every date in the list. Assuming you have a sorted dateList with entries like this:

```
dateList = [
   {
       date: "startDate",
       end: false,
       index: 1
   },
    {
       date: "endDate",
       end: true,
       index: 1
   },
   ....
]
```

an Example code for calculation the duration in months would be something like this: It is not the nicest code, but maybe it is easier to understand like this. Any improvements are appreciated:

```
function calculateDurationAmountWithoutAddingOverlappingRanges(dateList) {
    var months = 0;
    var currentOverlappingList = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < dateList.length; i++) {

        var startExists = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < currentOverlappingList.length; j++) {
            if (!currentOverlappingList[j].end) {
                startExists = true;
            }
        }

        var amount = 0;
        if (startExists) {
            amount = monthDiff(dates[i-1].date, dates[i].date);
        }

        currentOverlappingList.push(dates[i]);

        // remove date from list if end date (means remove start and end)
        if (dates[i].end) {
            for(var k = 0; k < currentOverlappingList.length; k++) {
                if(currentOverlappingList[k].index == dates[i].index) {
                    currentOverlappingList.splice(k,1);
                }
            }
        }
        months += amount;
    }
    return months;
}
```